# Using the youtube-iframe-api, the playVideo() method does start the video in Chrome (works in Safari and FF)

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

Problem can be seen here: https://www.wgbh.org/news/local-news/2022/06/07/housing-is-in-short-supply-heres-why-that-matters

When clicking on the poster image play button, the poster image disappears and the video should start playing (triggered by `<player>.playVideo()` from the API).

However, in Chrome (and in Brave), the user must also click the YT native play button. No errors are shown from the `playVideo()` method.

The user click triggers the `play()` function in this code snippet (not live), I call playVideo() every half second. The initial video state is "video cued" but after that, the state never changes from "unstarted" and the video never plays.

```
     play () {
        console.log('Received play signal from poster')
        let playerState = this.player.getPlayerState().toString()
        const thePlayer = this.player
        console.log('Pre-play-signal state: ', PLAYER_STATES[playerState])
        let waitForPlay = setInterval(function () {
          thePlayer.playVideo()
          playerState = thePlayer.getPlayerState().toString()
          console.log('Interval play state: ', PLAYER_STATES[playerState])
          if (playerState === '1') {
            clearInterval(waitForPlay)
            console.log('Final play state: ', PLAYER_STATES[playerState])
          }
        }, 500)
      }
```

Response headers from the `playVideo()` requests:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.youtube.com
access-control-expose-headers: Client-Protocol, Content-Length, Content-Type, X-Bandwidth-Est, X-Bandwidth-Est2, X-Bandwidth-Est3, X-Bandwidth-App-Limited, X-Bandwidth-Est-App-Limited, X-Bandwidth-Est-Comp, X-Bandwidth-Avg, X-Head-Time-Millis, X-Head-Time-Sec, X-Head-Seqnum, X-Response-Itag, X-Restrict-Formats-Hint, X-Sequence-Num, X-Segment-Lmt, X-Walltime-Ms
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: private, max-age=21248
client-protocol: quic
content-length: 2097152
content-type: video/webm
cross-origin-resource-policy: cross-origin
date: Wed, 08 Jun 2022 20:19:21 GMT
expires: Wed, 08 Jun 2022 20:19:21 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 07 Jun 2022 13:41:59 GMT
server: gvs 1.0
timing-allow-origin: https://www.youtube.com
vary: Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-restrict-formats-hint: None
```

I have tried this a browser opened with the `--disable-web-security` flag, but no difference.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, just with Chrome and Edge, not with Firefox

Answer (score 1):

As I commented to your question, I had your same problem, both with Chrome and Edge. Not with Firefox (I haven't further browser installed, so I don't know with Safari, Opera, etc...).
After some day of search I got that the issue, at least for me, is that some browsers (as Chrome and Edge) don't allow to start a YouTube video that is unmuted (i.e. that reproduces a sound track along with the video) by an "external" command, i.e. by a javascript function.
 So they don't allow autoplay of the video as the page is loaded, or to start it by clicking something that is not a "native" control of the YT player. This behaviour, for my understanding, is due to prevent ads or whatever that isn't wanted by the browser user to start without his/her explicit consent.
 These browsers so allow these situations:

- autoplay (or play by an external command/script as in your case) if the video is muted;
- play of an unmuted video by an external command (or script) if the user has previously had some sort of interaction (click, tap, etc...) with the YT video player.

I am not a super expert, by the way, you should edit your code in order to load the video player with a "mute" state (it's easy to recognize it, when the volume icon has a slash/bar on it). 
I suppose that could be obtained by adding this line:

`thePlayer.mute();`

before you call the playVideo() function or, in the YT player constructor (playerVars section), add the keypair:

`'mute' : 1`

Be aware of this: I was tempted to mute the video, check its state and, once it's started to umute it with the function player.unMute() (thePlayer.unMute() in your case). 
Unluckily this trick doesn't work, i.e. if Chrome and Edge detect the user hasn't had any interaction with the player, as you call the unMute() function, the video stops playing (!!!).
Hope this helps